# Prevent android from splitting line at a specific point?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the text `Improve and Personalize App Name`.

The way I have it in my layout, it runs out of space and wraps to the next line such that the text is like `Improve and Personalize App\nName`.

But it looks weird to have the app name be split across lines.

How do I specify to Android not to split the app name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it works.

You can use a character that looks like a space but isn't a space. Android will consider your app name to be one word, even if it isn't.

I used `&#160;` so my string became `Improve and Personalize App&#160;Name`

Comment: Your method is kinda hacky. The text _`Improve and Personalize App&#160;Name`_ would still break in a smaller device screen. Assuming that you put `&#160;` between each word, a smaller device would be forced to break the word, adding a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on the screen size of the device. So what you see is weird for the device you test on. It can be more weird in other devices or perfect for others. If you really need this text in one line then you must create different layouts of the activity/fragment for different screen sizes (even for different orientations) and in each of them define smaller or bigger textsize for the text.

Or use 2 TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Improve and Personalize "/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If the 2nd TextView is too big it will fall down to the next line.

Comment: I see no reason why my solution wouldn't work on other devices. I want it to wrap to the next line, I just want it to wrap before the app name instead of in the middle of it.